# Obtain most recent value by date for each group at observation level

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, plyr

Hopefully I can explain this is a way that is easy to understand.   I want to obtain the price of a particular product for the most recent date at the observation level.  This should progress overtime.  For example, I have dates from 2014-2015...the 'most recent price' should change day by day as time goes on.

In order words the desired answer is always the most recent value with a date less than the current observation's date.

```
   df = data.frame(dates = c('2015-08-09','2015-08-10','2015-08-15','2015-07-31','2015-09-09','2015-09-12','2015-09-19'), group=c(rep("A",5),"B","B"), price=c(5,15,3,24,10,13,2), desired_answer = c(24,5,15,NA,3,NA,13))
```

Any advice on how to do this in R?

Comment: If you tagged this with `dplyr`, you could just use `lag` here, as in `df %>% arrange(as.Date(dates)) %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(res = lag(price))`. I'm sure there are many dupes for this one.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using a combination of dplyr functions as follows

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  arrange(dates)  %>% 
  mutate(answer = lag(price, 1))
```